# Google App Script: Javascript runtime exited unexpectedly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have written an app script that will interact with the bigQuery API and fetch the bigQuery results.

API is been hit around close to 60-70 times. In this process sometimes I'm getting the following error message:

> "JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly"

could someone help me here?

Let me know if you need any additional information

```
function fetchTables() {
  var timezone = "GMT+" + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
  Logger.log(date);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tables');
  var value = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();

  var projectId = 'corpbi-dev';

  var request = {
    query: 'select table_id from [corpbi-dev:' + value + '.__TABLES__]'
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

   var rows = queryResults.rows;

  if (rows) {
    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
  }

  var queries = [];
  var totalbytes = [];
  var timelapsed = [];
  var rowcount = [];
  var jobcode = [];

  var finalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Final Metrics');

  for(var i=1; i<=data.length; i++) {
  var sql = "SELECT stage_loading_query FROM (SELECT stage_loading_query, job_start_time FROM [corpbi-dev:etl_log.job_details] WHERE target_table LIKE '%"+ value + "." + data[i-1]+"%' " +
    "GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 2 desc) LIMIT 1"

  var request1 = {
    query: sql
  };
  var queryResults1 = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request1, projectId);
  var sql1 = queryResults1.rows;
    //Logger.log(sql1);
 //   break;

  if (sql1) {
    // Append the results.
    var data1 = new Array(sql1.length);
    for (var k = 0; k < sql1.length; k++) {
      var cols = sql1[k].f;
      data1[k] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data1[k][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
  }
   queries.push(data1);
     
  }
  //Logger.log(queries.length);
  finalSheet.getRange(2, 1, queries.length).setValues(queries);
//  queries = finalSheet.getRange(2, 1, finalSheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  var endtime = (new Date()).getTime();
  Logger.log(endtime);


  for(var i=1; i<=queries.length; i++) {
    var sqlstmt = queries[i-1];


    try{
      var request2 = {
    query: sqlstmt,
    useLegacySql: true
  };
    var sleepTimeMs = 50000;
  var queryResults2 = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request2, projectId);
       var jobId1 = queryResults2.jobReference.jobId;
      while (!queryResults2.jobComplete) {
        Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
        sleepTimeMs *= 2;
        queryResults2 = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId1);
        //continue;
      }

  var queryDetails = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId1);
  totalbytes.push(queryDetails.statistics.totalBytesProcessed);
  timelapsed.push(queryDetails.statistics.totalSlotMs);
  rowcount.push(queryResults2.totalRows);
}
    catch(e){
      try{
      var request2 = {
    query: sqlstmt,
    useLegacySql: false
  };

    var sleepTimeMs = 50000;
    var queryResults2 = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request2, projectId);
    var jobId1 = queryResults2.jobReference.jobId;
    while(!queryResults2.jobComplete) {
          Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
        sleepTimeMs *= 2;
        queryResults2 = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId1);
       // continue;
      }

  var queryDetails = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId1);
  totalbytes.push(queryDetails.statistics.totalBytesProcessed);
  timelapsed.push(queryDetails.statistics.totalSlotMs);
  rowcount.push(queryResults2.totalRows);
}
      catch(e){
      Logger.log(e);
    }
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  finalSheet.getRange(i+1, 2,).setValue((totalbytes[i-1]/1048576).toFixed(2) + 'MB');
  finalSheet.getRange(i+1, 3,).setValue((timelapsed[i-1]/1000).toFixed(2) + 's');
  finalSheet.getRange(i+1, 4,).setValue((rowcount[i-1]));

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your javascript code

Comment: Hello sravan, kindly open your script & click on `View>Executions`. There, you should see a report of all the executions of the script. Please do select one of the ones that failed, and attach the logs associated to the execution so we may inspect them.

Comment: Furthermore, may I ask what version of GAS are you using? If you open `View>Manifest File` within the Apps Script editor, do you see a `runtimeVersion` tag? what does it say? Could you also share the code?

Comment: Hi Carlessgg97, This is the error log "Dec 26, 2019, 6:05:36 PM Error The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly." and runtimeversion is V8

Comment: Hey Sravan, was the answer I published useful to you? I'd love to know how you moved on with the issue you originally presented. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Carl, Thanks for the suggestion, now its saying exceeded execution time. I'm looking into it... if you have any suggestions let me know(code is already tagged). I think after changing to 'STABLE'  javascript runtime is not there.

Comment: Hi sravan, I am also using the Big Query API and I'm getting the same error message.  I only get the message when I try to convert one of the larger queries into a nested array, indicating that it may be a memory issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The V8 Runtime for Google Apps Script is known to be on Alpha stage, which means you may encounter some bugs/errors.

In order to use the stable GAS version, you only need to change the `runtimeVersion` value in your script's manifest from `V8` to `STABLE`.

Comment: I'm one of the unlucky users who just put a lot of work into a Google apps script project, only for this message to start appearing.  Also my debugger has stopped working.  I can't switch to the previous runtime, because that also breaks the script.  All of my declarations are 'let' rather than 'var'.  I'm really hoping that they make the ES6 version stable soon...

Comment: When I put `STABLE` instead of `V8`, I get an error

Answer (score 1):

## `JavaScript Runtime Exited Unexpectedly` - Solved with Exponential Backoff

This post details how I resolved the "JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly" error due to exceeding data size limits.

### Problem

The error text from logs:

> JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly

### Debugging

Unfortunately, pinpointing the exact cause was challenging since generic `console.log` statements were needed. Eventually, I identified the culprit: the `data.concat(newData)` line caused an issue when dealing with large datasets.

### Solution

I tried to fix that with exponential beckof helper.

1. Figured out where the problem is
2. Added ExpBackof to the function.

```
  const func = () => data.concat(newData);
  results = expBackofWithResultCheck_(func)
```

My version of `expBackofWithResultCheck_`:

```
/**
 * Expected Result Backof
 * 
 * @param {function} functionToRun
 * @param {function} [isValid]
 * @param {number} [numIterations]
 * @param {number} [maxDelay]
 */
function expBackofWithResultCheck_(
  functionToRun, 
  isValid, 
  numIterations = 5, 
  maxDelay=1000) {
  if (!isValid) {
    isValid = (elt) => elt !== null && elt !== undefined;
  }
  let result, delay;
  for (let i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      console.warn(`We are running "${functionToRun.name}" again: ${i + 1} times...`);
    }
    result = functionToRun();
    if (isValid(result)) {
      return result;
    }
    delay = getBackoffTime2Delay_(i, maxDelay);
    console.info('Backof goes sleeping for ' + delay);
    Utilities.sleep(delay);
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * returns ms to wait after each backoff operation
 * 
 * @param {Number} i
 * @param {Number} maxDelay - ms
 * 
 * @returns {Number} delay
 */
function getBackoffTime2Delay_(i, maxDelay = 1000) {
  return Math.min(maxDelay, 2 ** i * 100);
}
```

### PS. Real solution

Here are my tries to fix the data overloading:

1. The `concat` method did wrong → error.
2. New JS method: `data = [...data, ...newData];` → error.
3. An algorithm for adding data by chunks → error.
4. `data.push(row)` instead of concat → less often error

My final solution was to stick with `data.push(row)` and `expBackof`. My data source is batch API calls, so I've also reduced the data to get only the fields needed.