# How do I resolve Calendar Add-on Error in GSuite Apps Script?

Tags: calendar, google-apps-script-addon, gsuite-addons

We have launched UnMeet Calendar Add-on on GSuite Marketplace SDK. The code was reviewed and approved by GSM Reviews team and OAuth team. It has been tested multiple times by our team as well.

However, some users have complained about an error when they click the "Lets get started" button on Home Page of the Add-on  which says "Something went wrong while executing the add-on."

We referred to StackOverFlow and changed our runtimeversion to STABLE from V8. Still the error persists for these users.

It seems like a bug in Google Apps Script. Kindly help us resolve the issue at the earliest.

Comment: If this issue occurs only occasionally for certain users, your best would be to contact GSuite support as recommended on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/162813340).

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks. we have contacted them. here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162912351

Comment: What i Meant is that you should contact [GSuite support](https://gsuite.google.com/support/?referral-tabs_activeEl=g-suite-and-gcp) instead of filing a bug on Public Issue Tracker, given that the problem seems to be account specific and not a general bug.

Comment: @ziganotschka this is not account specific issue as has been confirmed by GSuite Support team. GSuite Marketplace team has already reviewed and approved the code, along with OAuth consent team which has also done extensive review. GSuite Support asked us to contact this public bug tracker. It seems a platform issue as has been hinted in other places (see link here) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488807/google-app-script-javascript-runtime-exited-unexpectedly